# AttributeError when accessing MultiIndex of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(80, 120, size=(4,2)),
                   index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['English', 'Japanese'], ['like', 'dislike']]),
                   columns=['girl', 'boy']
                   )
print(df1)
```

How can I access just the `English` rows? This does not work:

```
print(df1.English)  # there I get error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'English'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `English` is part of the row index, but `df.English` tries to access a column.
2. The row index is a MultiIndex, so it should be [indexed as a tuple](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index) of `(language, dis/like)`.

---

To select the `English` rows, use [`xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) to get the cross-section:

```
df1.xs('English')

#          girl  boy
# like       87   91
# dislike    95   89
```

Or in this case, [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) also works since the language is the first level of the MultiIndex:

```
df1.loc['English']

#          girl  boy
# like       87   91
# dislike    95   89
```